# Python error with Flask-SQLAlchemy : init_app() first

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

Good afternoon, I have a small Flask application where I use Flask-SQLAlchemy as ORM and Flask-Script to manage the database. From manage.py I can register the tables, add data and delete the tables in addition to running the Flask development server with the command "python3 manage.py runserver". From this server everything works ok but when performing the deployment on an Apache Linux production server when doing any query in the DB it gives me the following error in the LOG:
"***AssertionError: The sqlalchemy extension was not registered to the current application.  Please make sure to call init_app() first.*"**

This is the code of my project:

```
#main.py

from flask import Flask
#all imports


app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object(DevelopmentConfig)

csrf = CSRFProtect(app)


@app.route('/',methods = ['GET','POST'])
def login():
from models import Usuario
login_form = LoginForm(request.form)
if request.method == 'POST' and login_form.validate():
    username = login_form.username.data
    password= login_form.password.data
    usuario = Usuario.query.filter_by(username = username).first()
    if usuario is not None:#Ha encontrado el usuario
        if usuario.verify_password(password):
            # Login OK
            flash(u"Bienvenido {0}".format(username),'ok')
            return render_template('login_ok.html',username=username )
        else:
            #password not ok
            flash(u"Contraseña incorrecta",'error')
            #redirect(url_for("login"))
    else:
        flash(u"Usuario no encontrado",'error')
        #redirect(url_for("login"))
return render_template("login.html",form = login_form)
```

###############################################

```
#models.py
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy 
from sqlalchemy import Boolean, Column, ForeignKey
from sqlalchemy import DateTime, Integer, String, Text, Float
from werkzeug.security import generate_password_hash, check_password_hash

db = SQLAlchemy()


class Usuario(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'usuarios'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key = True)
    username = Column(String(50), unique = True)
    password = Column(String(128))
    nombre = Column(String(50))
    email = Column(String(50),unique = True)
    admin = Column(Boolean,default=False)

    def __init__(self, username, password, nombre, email,admin):
        self.username = username
        self.password = self.__create_password(password)
        self.nombre = nombre
        self.email = email
        self.admin = admin
    
    #declaramos una funcion privada para encriptar el password
    def __create_password(self,password):
        return generate_password_hash(password)

    #declaramos una funcion privada para comparar los passwords encriptados(True si son iguales)
    def verify_password(self,password):
        return check_password_hash(self.password, password)
```

##########################################

```
#manage.py
from flask_script import Manager
from main import app,db #importamos app,db desde main.py
from models import Usuario

from flask_wtf.csrf import CSRFProtect

manager = Manager(app)
app.config['DEBUG'] = True 


db.init_app(app)


@manager.command
def hello():
    print("hello")

@manager.command
def create_tables():
    db.create_all()
    


@manager.command
def drop_tables():
    db.drop_all()


@manager.command
def add_data_tables():
    db.create_all()
    
    usuario = Usuario(username = "user",password = "user",nombre= "User", 
    email="user@hotmail.com",admin=False)
    db.session.add(usuario)
    db.session.commit()

@manager.command
def create_admin(): 
    usuario = {"username": input("Usuario:"),
               "password": input("Password:"),
               "nombre": input("Nombre completo:"),
               "email": input("Email:"),
               "admin": True}
    usu = Usuario(**usuario)
    db.session.add(usu)
    db.session.commit()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    manager.run()
```

##################

Can someone help me? I have reviewed the documentation but I cannot find the error.

Answer (score 0):

Your sqlalchemy needs to know which is your flask app
You should change this:

```
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy 
from sqlalchemy import Boolean, Column, ForeignKey
from sqlalchemy import DateTime, Integer, String, Text, Float
from werkzeug.security import generate_password_hash, check_password_hash

db = SQLAlchemy()


class Usuario(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'usuarios'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key = True)
    username = Column(String(50), unique = True)
    password = Column(String(128))
    nombre = Column(String(50))
    email = Column(String(50),unique = True)
    admin = Column(Boolean,default=False)

    def __init__(self, username, password, nombre, email,admin):
        self.username = username
        self.password = self.__create_password(password)
        self.nombre = nombre
        self.email = email
        self.admin = admin
    
    #declaramos una funcion privada para encriptar el password
    def __create_password(self,password):
        return generate_password_hash(password)

    #declaramos una funcion privada para comparar los passwords encriptados(True si son iguales)
    def verify_password(self,password):
        return check_password_hash(self.password, password)
```

to:

```
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy 
from sqlalchemy import Boolean, Column, ForeignKey
from sqlalchemy import DateTime, Integer, String, Text, Float
from werkzeug.security import generate_password_hash, check_password_hash
# You need to import you app = Flask(__name__) from you main.py
from main import app
# And pass it to SQLAlchemy like this:
db = SQLAlchemy(app=app)


class Usuario(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'usuarios'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key = True)
    username = Column(String(50), unique = True)
    password = Column(String(128))
    nombre = Column(String(50))
    email = Column(String(50),unique = True)
    admin = Column(Boolean,default=False)

    def __init__(self, username, password, nombre, email,admin):
        self.username = username
        self.password = self.__create_password(password)
        self.nombre = nombre
        self.email = email
        self.admin = admin
    
    #declaramos una funcion privada para encriptar el password
    def __create_password(self,password):
        return generate_password_hash(password)

    #declaramos una funcion privada para comparar los passwords encriptados(True si son iguales)
    def verify_password(self,password):
        return check_password_hash(self.password, password)
```

Comment: look at your db = Sqlalchemy() that is where the change is needed

Answer (score 0):

With that solution it doesn't work for me either. I have seen another way to do it but now it gives me an error when accessing the DB in the log.
My code now:

```
#main.py
from flask import Flask
from config import DevelopmentConfig
from flask import render_template,request,flash
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from forms import LoginForm
from flask_wtf.csrf import CSRFProtect

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object(DevelopmentConfig)

csrf = CSRFProtect(app)
db = SQLAlchemy(app)


@app.route('/',methods = ['GET','POST'])
def login():
..
```

##########

```
#manage.py
from flask_script import Manager
from main import app,db #importamos app,db desde main.py
from models import Usuario

from flask_wtf.csrf import CSRFProtect

manager = Manager(app)
app.config['DEBUG'] = True


@manager.command
def hello():



   .
```

###########

```
#models.py
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy 
from sqlalchemy import Boolean, Column, ForeignKey
from sqlalchemy import DateTime, Integer, String, Text, Float
from werkzeug.security import generate_password_hash, check_password_hash

from main import db

class Usuario(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'usuarios'
.
.
```

##########
On the development server it works ok but on apache not work

Apache Error log: [Mon May 24 19:16:53.895332 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 17380:tid 140379029477120] [client 192.168.0.15:42372] sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) unable to open database file, referer: http://192.168.0.15/
[Mon May 24 19:16:53.895344 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 17380:tid 140379029477120] [client 192.168.0.15:42372] (Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/14/e3q8), referer: http://192.168.0.15/